# How to create partitioned and bucked external table in hive with delta directories?

Tags: azure, hive, hdfs, external-tables, hive-partitions

I created a partitioned and bucketed table in HIVE by merging many files. Due to some reasons, that table cannot be accessed from HIVE, maybe its metadata is lost, though the data is there along with partitions,delta directories and buckets.

I have created an external table in HIVE pointing to that directory i.e /hive/warehouse/database/table and run **MSCK REPAIR TABLE** command as well. But I cannot run any query on that table, it gives following error:

```
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
wasb://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/hive/warehouse/cdr.db/cdr_main/district=XYZ is a directory 
not a file
```

The error is due to delta directories as they exist in the partition folders. So, is there any way to repair the table or its metadata, so that I can use the data instead of redoing everything?